# ¿Habra una forma de ocupar menos funciones en vez de una función para cada opción?

Tags: javascript, html5, web

quería saber si hay alguna forma de usar menos funciones en javascript en vez de una por cada opción por ejemplo:

```
var Result;

function L_FB() {
  Result = confirm("Desea ayudarnos usando el link shortener?");
  if (Result == true) {
    window.open('Direcion X', '_blank');
  }
  else {
    window.open('https://freebitco.in/?r=4606306&tag==Mundo-Bitcoin', '_blank');
  }
}

function L_BF() {
  Result = confirm("Desea ayudarnos usando el link shortener?");
  if (Result == true) {
    window.open('Direcion x', '_blank');
  }
  else {
    window.open('http://bitfun.co/?ref=F217B6FD0E60', '_blank');
  }
}

function L_BB() {
  Result = confirm("Desea ayudarnos usando el link shortener?");
  if (Result == true) {
    window.open('Direcion x', '_blank');
  }
  else {
    window.open('Direcion x', '_blank');
  }
}
```

y en vez de ocupar la misma función y solo cambiarle de nombre de la misma,  que sepa que elemento clickeo y asi mandarte al link correspondiente 
Cualquier consejo ayudaría.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenes que definir los parámetros (`imagen`, `enlace1`, `enlace2`) de la función y reemplazar los valores fijos por el nombre del parámetro. Luego, al momento de llamar a la función se pasan los argumentos (`idImagen`, `www.foo.com`, `www.bar.com`) con los que va a realizar las operaciones.

```
// Definición de la función
function redirigir(imagen, enlaceDirecto, enlace1, enlace2) {
    var img = document.getElementById(imagen);

    img.addEventListener('click', function() {

        var Result = confirm('Desea ayudarnos usando el link shortener?');

        if (Result == true) {
          window.open(enlace1, '_blank');
        } else {
          window.open(enlace2, '_blank');
        }
    })
}

// Llamadas a la función
redirigir('idImagen', 'https://www.foo.com', 'https://www.bar.com');
redirigir('idImagen2', 'http://www.hello.com', 'http://www.world.com');
```

Comment: Pero no eso llamaría el mismo enlace le de click a lo que le de click?
Porqué por ejemplo: Tengo 2 imágenes diferentes y quiero que hacer click en una me mande a una pagina diferente y en la otra imagen me mande a otro enlace. Al punto que quiero llegar es que la función sepa que imagen clickio el usuario y dirigirlo al enlace correspondiente aparte ay dos enlaces en la funcion uno que si le da en aceptar que lo enviara al link con anuncio y el otro que lo enviara directo.

Comment: @ProgramadorUniversal Recién edite mi respuesta, creo que lo mejor es identificar a cada imagen con un identificador (ID) y pasarlo como argumento al llamar a la función.

Comment: Si es lo que estoy viendo y ya pegue el código y lo estoy probando pero me aparece que esto en el console log
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function
    at redirigir (Link-Btc2.js:5)
    at Link-Btc2.js:16

No se si me pudieras ayudar con ese problema

Comment: Bueno muchas gracias por la ayuda me diste una idea de como hacerlo yo allí veo el problema de que .addEventListener y lo de getElementBy(Id,ClassName o Tag) porque también hoy en la tarde hice eso y me marco el mismo error.

Comment: De nada. Volví a editar la respuesta, te recomiendo que uses id en este caso porque tenes que identificar de forma única a cada imagen. ;)

Comment: Ok lo usare es que antes había visto algunos videos que dicen que ya no es tan recomendable usar el atributo id y que es mejor usar el atributo class pero bueno muchas gracias por todo

Comment: Una ultima pregunta le tengo que poner a la imagen onclick="redirigir()" o hay otra forma de llamar a la función?

Comment: En tu archivo javascript, se puede llamar de esta forma: `redirigir('img', 'url')`. En img tenes que colocar el ID que tenga la imagen `<img id="primero">` y en url va la página a donde quieres redirigir. Ejemplo: `redirigir('primero', 'www.bar.com')`. Deberías quitar el atributo onclick de tu HTML, ya que no es necesario.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias intentare hacer lo mayor posible.
Ya os dejo de molestar jeje gracias